# Getting data for a user in a month

Tags: sql, postgresql, select, group-by

**(The database is Postgres )**

Let's say I have a table races with `columns` `(user_name , race_time , race_speed , race_no).`

Each users can have multiple races . I want to get data for each month and show for each month how many races are played in that month. ***But I also want to show which user played the most and which played has the maximum speed.***

```
select 
    extract ( month from race_time) as month,
    extract ( year from race_time) as year, 
    count(race_no) as total_races 
from races r
group by year,month
order by year desc,month desc
```

The above `query` gives me each month and the total races but how can I find for each month which user played the most (that'd be one user)?

I hope someone could help me with this.

Comment: Which result do you expect if there's a tie?

Comment: If there is a tie then first user by using limit

Comment: Better use `DATE_TRUNC('month')` instead, as `EXTRACT` will give you the same value for the different years, so you will get messy results at the end.

Comment: Maybe try to create multiple select statements, where each one will be the "key" to create the "overall" select.

Meaning:
1. Create a select that holds mappings of RaceMonth – to number of races occurred.
2. Create a select that holds mappings of RaceMonth – to userId with the most races.
3. Create a select that holds mappings of RaceMonth – to userId with the max speed.

Join all by Month.

Comment: @Y.S you mean using union

Comment: No, I mean join.
Since month is the key here, and everything should be in month orientation, that's what you want.
You'll have a month column , a NumOfRaces column , a MaxSpeedColumn and a UserWithMost Races column.

Assuming each select statemnt of the "sub-selects" I suggested  holds a 1-1 record for each purpose, joining should give you 1-1 mappings as well.

Comment: @Y.S could you please post example or post an answer with example thanks

Comment: something like this (again, just a general idea)

Comment: SELECT  *
into #tmp1
FROM    
(
select 1 as Month , 'Bob' as UserwithMostRaces
 union
select 2 as Month , 'Alice' as UserwithMostRaces 
) a

SELECT  *
into #tmp2
FROM    
(
select 1 as Month , 'Guy' as UserWithFastestTime
 union
select 2 as Month , 'Ron' as UserWithFastestTime
) b

SELECT  *
into #tmp3
FROM    
(
select 1 as Month , 20 as TotalRaces
 union
select 2 as Month , 54 as TotalRaces
) c

Comment: SELECT  a.Month , a.UserwithMostRaces , b.UserWithFastestTime , max(c.TotalRaces )TotalRaces 
FROM    #tmp1 a
 inner join #tmp2 b
  on a.Month = b.Month
 inner join #tmp3 c
  on a.Month = b.Month
group by a.Month , a.UserwithMostRaces , b.UserWithFastestTime

Comment: @Y.S thanks I'll have a look at it

Comment: Of course, the work will be to assemble the three select statements, but once you have that, it makes it a lot simpler

Comment: You need to normalize your data structure. Separate your `race (race_no, race_time)`, your `driver (driver_no, user_name)` and your `race_driver (race_no, driver_no, speed)` entities.

Comment: @KouberSaparev I actually can't change schema at this point :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/c9d86/1)

```
with r as (
    select
        to_char(race_time, 'YYYY-MM') as month,
        user_name,
        count(*) as n_races,
        max(race_speed) as max_speed
    from races
    group by 1, 2
), total_races as (
    select sum(n_races) as total_races, month
    from r
    group by month
)
select *
from (
        select distinct on (month)
            month, user_name as user_most_races, n_races as most_races
        from r
        order by 1, 3 desc
    ) s
    inner join (
        select distinct on (month)
            month, user_name as user_max_speed, max_speed
        from r
        order by 1, 3 desc
    ) q using (month)
    inner join
    total_races using(month)
order by month
```

Comment: I didn't know that I could write query that way..wow thanks a ton mate.. :)

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT user_name), user_name, EXTRACT(month FROM race_time) AS month, EXTRACT(year FROM race_time) AS year
FROM races r
GROUP BY user_name, year, month
ORDER BY year desc, month desc
```

Comment: That would be give number of users...how do I get the username with highest speed and most no of races ?

Comment: Ermmm, well this answers your question, i dont want to include something that isnt in the question as it could cause confusion in the future. But if you change your question to include that or create a new question i will have a go

Comment: And this would have to be a separate query? as this is for the users who did the most races per month

Comment: ahh, apologies :) i think you need to use a cte for this

Answer (score -1):

Try it!

```
USE [DATABASE_NAME]
GO

--this is calculating the which user played the most
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[GetHighestPlayedRaceUserByYearMonth] 
(
    -- Add the parameters for the function here
    @Year INT, @Month INT
)
RETURNS NVARCHAR(50)
AS
BEGIN
    -- Declare the return variable here
    DECLARE @UserName NVARCHAR(50)

    -- Add the T-SQL statements to compute the return value here
    DECLARE @TempTbl TABLE(Played INT,UserName NVARCHAR(50))

    INSERT INTO @TempTbl(Played,UserName)
    SELECT 
        COUNT(race_no) AS Played,
        [user_name] AS UserName 

    FROM Table_1
    WHERE 
        YEAR(race_time)=@Year and
        MONTH(race_time)=@Month

    GROUP BY 
        MONTH(race_time),
        YEAR(race_time), 
        [user_name]
    ORDER BY 
        YEAR(race_time) DESC,
        MONTH(race_time) DESC, 
        COUNT(race_no) DESC

    DECLARE @MaxPlayed INT
    SET @MaxPlayed=(SELECT TOP 1 Played FROM @TempTbl ORDER BY Played DESC)

    DECLARE @TempTbl2 TABLE(ID INT IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,UserName NVARCHAR(50))
    INSERT INTO @TempTbl2
    SELECT UserName FROM @TempTbl WHERE Played=@MaxPlayed

    DECLARE @ROWCOUNT INT
    SET @ROWCOUNT=1
    SET @UserName=''
    WHILE (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM @TempTbl2)>=@ROWCOUNT
    BEGIN
        IF (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM @TempTbl2)=@ROWCOUNT
        BEGIN
            SET @UserName= @UserName+(SELECT UserName FROM @TempTbl2 WHERE ID=@ROWCOUNT)
        END
        ELSE
        BEGIN
            SET @UserName= @UserName+(SELECT UserName FROM @TempTbl2 WHERE ID=@ROWCOUNT)+','
        END
        SET @ROWCOUNT=@ROWCOUNT+1
    END

    -- Return the result of the function
    RETURN @UserName

END

GO

--this is calculating which user played with the maximum speed
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[GetMaxRaceSpeedUserByYearMonth] 
(
    -- Add the parameters for the function here
    @Year INT, @Month INT
)
RETURNS NVARCHAR(50)
AS
BEGIN
    -- Declare the return variable here
    DECLARE @UserName NVARCHAR(50)

    -- Add the T-SQL statements to compute the return value here
    DECLARE @TempTbl TABLE(MaxRaceSpeed INT,UserName NVARCHAR(50))

    INSERT INTO @TempTbl(MaxRaceSpeed,UserName)
    SELECT 
        MAX(race_speed) AS MaxRaceSpeed,
        [user_name] AS UserName 

    FROM Table_1
    WHERE 
        YEAR(race_time)=@Year and
        MONTH(race_time)=@Month

    GROUP BY 
        MONTH(race_time),
        YEAR(race_time), 
        [user_name]
    ORDER BY 
        YEAR(race_time) DESC,
        MONTH(race_time) DESC, 
        COUNT(race_no) DESC

    DECLARE @MaxRaceSpeed INT
    SET @MaxRaceSpeed=(SELECT TOP 1 MaxRaceSpeed FROM @TempTbl ORDER BY MaxRaceSpeed DESC)

    DECLARE @TempTbl2 TABLE(ID INT IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,UserName NVARCHAR(50))
    INSERT INTO @TempTbl2
    SELECT UserName FROM @TempTbl WHERE MaxRaceSpeed=@MaxRaceSpeed

    DECLARE @ROWCOUNT INT
    SET @ROWCOUNT=1
    SET @UserName=''
    WHILE (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM @TempTbl2)>=@ROWCOUNT
    BEGIN
        IF (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM @TempTbl2)=@ROWCOUNT
        BEGIN
            SET @UserName= @UserName+(SELECT UserName FROM @TempTbl2 WHERE ID=@ROWCOUNT)
        END
        ELSE
        BEGIN
            SET @UserName= @UserName+(SELECT UserName FROM @TempTbl2 WHERE ID=@ROWCOUNT)+','
        END
        SET @ROWCOUNT=@ROWCOUNT+1
    END

    -- Return the result of the function
    RETURN @UserName

END

GO

--Select Query
SELECT 
    MONTH(race_time) AS [Month],
    YEAR(race_time) AS [Year],
    COUNT(race_no) AS RacePlayed,
    dbo.GetHighestPlayedRaceUserByYearMonth(YEAR(race_time),MONTH(race_time)) AS MaximunPlayedUser,
    dbo.GetMaxRaceSpeedUserByYearMonth(YEAR(race_time),MONTH(race_time)) AS MaximunSpeedUser
FROM TABLE_NAME
GROUP BY MONTH(race_time),YEAR(race_time)
ORDER BY YEAR(race_time) DESC,MONTH(race_time) DESC
```

Comment: The question is tagged [Postgresql] and your answer is for [SQL Server]